# Format event_date and event_timestamp Big query while querying data in custom query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Hi following is my query to fetch some data in big `query` want to know how can we format `date` and `time stamp`

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    (
    SELECT
      x.value
    FROM
      UNNEST(user_properties) x
    WHERE
      x.key='restaurantName'
      AND x.value IS NOT NULL).string_value AS restaurantName,
    event_date AS date,
    event_timestamp AS time,
    event_name AS Event,
    (
    SELECT
      x.value
    FROM
      UNNEST(user_properties) x
    WHERE
      x.key='restaurantId'
      AND x.value IS NOT NULL).string_value AS restaurantID,
    (
    SELECT
      x.value
    FROM
      UNNEST(user_properties) x
    WHERE
      x.key='user_id'
      AND x.value IS NOT NULL).string_value AS user
  FROM
    `analytics.events_*`
  WHERE
    event_name = "OrderSummary"
    AND app_info.id = "app_Id"
  ORDER BY
    event_timestamp ASC)
WHERE
  NOT(restaurantName IS NULL
    OR restaurantID="someName")
```

i am filtering data right but unable to format

[image]

Comment: what format you expect to have in output?

Comment: @Mikhali date = 28-11-2019 and time = 04:22:13 like this how i can do this in above query.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> format you expect to have in output? date = 28-11-2019 and time = 04:22:13

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Change/fix is just in below two lines

```
event_date AS date,
event_timestamp AS time,
```

So, instead of above  - use below

```
FORMAT_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) AS date, 
FORMAT_TIME('%T', TIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp))) time,
```

and respective output columns will be like

```
Row date        time     
1   28-11-2019  04:22:13
```

Note: I assume that `event_date` field is of STRING data type. If it actually an INT64 - you just need to ue `CAST(event_date AS STRING)` instead of `event_date`

Comment: This perfectly worked for me !!!! @Mikhail Thank you you are BOSS !!! :))

Answer (score 6):

Transform to `TIMESTAMP`, then `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP()`:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT 1574914933030017 ms)


SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(ms)
  , FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(ms))
FROM data


2019-11-28 04:22:13.030017 UTC
28/11/2019 04:22
```

Comment: Hey this is also right but above one worked for me :)